# Error in function for Selection-Sort

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting, data-structures

My code for selection-sort

```
#include <stdio.h>

void selection_sort(int a[], int n);

int main()
{
    int size;

    printf("Enter the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    int b[size],i = 0;
    printf("Enter %d integers to be sorted: ",size);
    while(i++ < size)
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    selection_sort(b, size);

    printf("Sorted integers(by selection sort) are: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
          printf("%d",b[i]);

    return 0;       
}

void selection_sort(int a[], int n)
{   
    while(n >= 0 )
    {
        if(n == 0)
            break;
        else
        {
            int i = 0, c = 0;
            int largest = a[0];
            while(i++ < n)
                if(largest < a[i])
                {
                    c = i ;
                    largest = a[i];
                }
            int temp = a[--n];
            a[n] = largest;
            a[c] = temp;
            selection_sort(a, n);
       } 

    }

}
```

on sorting the array in ascending order

```
3    4    1    2
```

is giving weird output

```
2293388    4    3    0
```

I checked this many time but failed to remove the problem.
What should I do to work it properly?
**Algorithm used** :
 1. search for largest element in the array.
 2. Move largest element to the last position of array.
 3. Call itself recursively to sort the first n -1 element of the array.

*Please don't give any other solution otherwise I will get confused.*

Comment: What is the output you expect and what is weird about the output you receive? Also enough code to see how you call the function would help. If `n` is the size of your array then accessing `a[n]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour OK, let me edit

Comment: How have you "checked this"?  Stepping through with a  debugger would show you that there are some problems with the indexes being used (for example, the code never seems to check `a[1]` against `largest`).  Even if you can't use a debugger for some reason, a couple `printf()`'s dumping values of interest (such as `largest`, `i`, `c`, `n`, and the array values) at each step would show you what's going wrong pretty quickly.

Comment: @MichaelBurr; Now it is giving `4 3 0 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Ah, I see what goes wrong. First of all, `while (i++ < n)` does not do exactly what you expect it to do. It checks if the condition `i < n` is true, then it increments `i`. However, it seems that after the conditional check, `i` is already incremented in the body. So for example,

```
while (i++ < n)
   printf ("%d ", i);
```

will print out (with `n=4`):

```
1 2 3 4
```

So you first need to change that. Secondly, the outer while-loop is not at all necessary. Using one loop will suffice. Again, change the while loop in here to `while (i < n)` and increment `i` in the body. SO the final code will be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void selection_sort(int a[], int n);

int main()
{
    int size;

    printf("Enter the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    int b[size], i = 0;
    printf("Enter %d integers to be sorted: ", size);
    while(i < size) {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
        i++;
    }

    selection_sort(b, size);

    printf("Sorted integers(by selection sort) are: ");
    i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
          printf("%d ", b[i]);

    printf ("\n");
    return 0;       
}

void selection_sort(int a[], int n)
{   
    if(n == 0)
        return;
    else
    {
        int i = 0, c = 0;
        int largest = a[0];
        while(i < n) {
            if(largest < a[i])
            {
                c = i;
                largest = a[i];
            }
            i++;
        }

        int temp = a[--n];
        a[n] = a[c];
        a[c] = temp;
        selection_sort(a, n);
    } 
}
```

I tested this with your given input (`3 4 1 2`) and it prints out a sorted list: `1 2 3 4`.

Comment: It is giving the output `0 1 2 3`

Comment: Then I am curious what your arguments for the function are and how you print out the array elements.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see such weird big numbers, its usually an array out of bounds issue. Please take a small data-set, say 5-6 numbers, and walk through your program. I am sure you can fix it. Good luck!!